# Add selection from dropdown to list

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html

I have a big dropdown list with the id `inventory`. Once I choose an option and click the `Añadir` button, the name of the option should be saved, so as its quantity. It can be added more than 1 option, in order to create a list.

The main problem now is that when I press `Añadir` button, it copies its name and quantity, but not only just once, it copies the same number of times as its selected quantity. It should just copy once: if I select "ABB Inverter(PVI 3.6)" and its "Cantidad" is 2, it should appear exactly one line with "ABB Inverter(PVI 3.6)" and "2"

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<!-- CSS -->
<style type="text/css">
/* general */
*, .border-box {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* tr.output */
tr.output {
    vertical-align: top;
}

tr.output > td > * {
    width: 100%;
}
</style> 

<!-- HTML -->
<form name="InventoryUp">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor="#97d700">
            <h2>Equipo(s) a ser utilizados</h2>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#D4D4D4"></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#D4D4D4"><b><em>Cantidad (#)</em></b>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#D4D4D4">
            <select id="inventory" size="1">
                <option id="0">Seleccione un equipo</option>
                <option id="abbi5000">ABB Inverter(5000)</option>
                <option id="abbiPVI3.6">ABB Inverter(PVI 3.6)</option>
                <option id="abbiPVI4.2">ABB Inverter(PVI 4.2)</option>
                <option id="bGE20">Breakers(GE 20 AMP)</option>

                <!-- Many more options... -->
            </select>
        </td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#D4D4D4">
            <input type="number" id="cantidad" placeholder="Ex: 5" size="1">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="actions">
        <td colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor="#D4D4D4">
            <!-- Añadir -->
            <input type="button" id="anadir" onclick="anadirEquipo()" value="Añadir" />

            <!-- Retirar -->
            <input type="button" id="retirar" onclick="retirarEquipos()" value="Retirar" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th align="center" bgcolor="#2AD2C9">
            <h4>Equipo(s) añadido(s):</h4>
        </th>
        <th align="center" bgcolor="#2AD2C9">
            <h4>Total:</h4>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="output">
        <td>
            <select type="text" id="equipos" multiple readonly>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" id="quantity" value="0" readonly />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>

<!-- JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript">
// vars
var pageLoaded = false,
    model = null;

// functions
function anadirEquipo() {
    var cantidad = +document.getElementById('cantidad').value || 1,
        selected = model.inventory.options[model.inventory.selectedIndex],
        choice;

    if (pageLoaded) {
        if (+selected.value !== 0) {
            model.quantity.value = +model.quantity.value + cantidad;

            while (cantidad-- > 0) {
                choice = document.createElement('option');
                choice.text = selected.text;
                choice.value = selected.value;

                model.equipos.add(choice);
            }
        }
    }
}

function retirarEquipos() {
    var options = model.equipos.options,
        i;

    if (pageLoaded) {
        for (i = 0; i < options.length; i) {
            if (options[i].selected) {
                model.equipos.remove(options[i]);
                model.quantity.value--;

            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}

// init
window.onload = function() {
    model = {
        inventory: document.getElementById('inventory'),
        equipos: document.getElementById('equipos'),
        quantity: document.getElementById('quantity')
    };

    pageLoaded = true;
};
</script>
```

Comment: Where should the added options go? which element?, Should they be appended after the `h2` element?

Comment: Exactly, after the h2 element

Comment: Here the name of the chose option: <input type="text" id="equipos" style="width: 350;"/>

And here the chose quantity: <input type="number" id="quantity"/>

This lines should be readonly, I already changed them.

Comment: Does the output list needs to be an input? Isn't better for it to be a div of divs, _(i.e: something that is unchangeable by nature in HTML)_?

Comment: Yes, I think you are probably right. Like I said, I'm new at this so I just used code that I saw somewhere...

Comment: I am using 2stacks which allows me to program HTML, that first part of the code needs to be inside <script language="javascript"> ??

Comment: Yes! I've just corrected that for you!

Comment: Thank you very much :) But its almost perfect ahah, what happens after the last edition is that the name of the selected piece is copied the same number of times as its selected quantity...

Comment: Yup I'm already taking care of that, just happen to appear some other big priority tasks to handle with! But I'll get back on this when I finish it!

Comment: Take your time, its already great that you are helping so much :)

If you don't mind (I hope I'm not abusing), now I have a bigger problem in JS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45870578/how-to-create-a-dynamic-dropdown-based-on-values-of-another-dynamic-dropdown/45870692#45870692

Take a look if you want!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Problem**

We want to be able to copy/select options from a `list A` to a `list B`, by clicking a `Button`, with the possibility of adding several times the same option *(i.e by specifying a* `Quantity` *of items to copy)*, also showing the `Total` of items added to `List B`.

**What do we need**

- **List A:** A `select` to select from, with some options on it.
- **Quantity:** An `input[number]` to define the quantity *(i.e how many copies of the currently selected option we want to add)*.
- **Button:** A `button` to copy elements from one list to another.
- **List B:** Some sort of `list` to show the copied/selected options *(i.e it can be anything, from a `div` to a `select` with `multiple` and `readonly` attributes)*.
- **Total:** Something to show the total of copied/selected items *(i.e it can be anything from a `div` to an `input[number]` with `readonly` attribute)*.

**What do we have**

- **List A:** A `select` with the id `inventory`
- **Quantity:** An `input` with the id `cantidad`
- **Button:** A `button` with the id `anadir`
- **List B:** A `select` with the id `equipos`
- **Total:** An `input` with the id `quantity`

**How to solve**

We start to create a function to copy items from `List A` to `List B`, in our case we call it `anadirEquipo`, notice how we're already referring all the DOM elements that we gonna need:

```js
function anadirEquipo () {
    var inventory = document.getElementById('inventory'), // List A
        cantidad = document.getElementById('cantidad'), // Quantity
        equipos = document.getElementById('equipos'); // List B
        total = document.getElementById('quantity') // Total

    // TODO: copy selected itens from ´inventory´ to ´equipos´
}
```

Now we need to get the selected option from `List A` *(i.e which is referenced in our `inventory` variable)*, and get the `Quantity`'s value *(present in our `cantidad` element)*, we can do that like this:

```js
// get the selected option from 'List A'
var selected = inventory.options[inventory.selectedIndex];

// get the .value from cantidad as number, or 1 if there is no .value
var quantity = +cantidad.value || 1;
```

We already have everything we need, now we should validate if there is a selected item on `List A`. Since on our `List A` we already have a *default item* with a value of `0` to represent an empty selection, we should check if the value of our currently selected item is `0`, if it's not, then we can increment our `Total` value by `Quantity` items:

```js
// validade if the selected item is not the default item
if (+selected.value !== 0) {

    // increment Total itens in 'List B' by 'quantity'
    total.value = total.value + quantity; 

    /** 
     * TODO: loop through 'List A' and copy the 
     * selected item, 'Quantity' times
     **/
}
```

Finally, we only need to copy the selected item from `List A` to `List B` as many times as in `Quantity`, to achieve that, we gonna *decrement* `Quantity` by `-1` until its `0`, and in each decrementation, we'll create a copy of the selected item and append it to `List B`:

```js
var choice;

while (quantity-- > 0) {
    // create a copy from the selected item
    choice = document.createElement('option');
    choice.text = selected.text;
    choice.value = selected.value;

    // append the copy to 'List B'
    equipos.add(choice);
}
```

At last, we'll have a function like this:

```js
function anadirEquipo () {
    var inventory = document.getElementById('inventory'), // List A
        cantidad = document.getElementById('cantidad'), // Quantity
        equipos = document.getElementById('equipos'), // List B
        total = document.getElementById('quantity'), // Total
        choice;

    // get the selected option from 'List A'
    var selected = inventory.options[inventory.selectedIndex];

    // get the .value from cantidad as number, or 1 if there is no .value
    var quantity = +cantidad.value || 1; 

    // validade if the selected item is not the default item
    if (+selected.value !== 0) {

        // increment Total itens from 'List B' by 'quantity'
        total.value = total.value + quantity; 

        while (quantity-- > 0) {
            // create a copy from the selected item
            choice = document.createElement('option');
            choice.text = selected.text;
            choice.value = selected.value;

            // append the copy to 'List B'
            equipos.add(choice);
        }
    }
}
```

In the end, we can also create a `retirarEquipos` function, that removes unwanted items from `List B` just by selecting them and calling the function. You can see an example of it in the snippet bellow.

**Final Solution**

```js
// vars
var pageLoaded = false,
    model = null;

// functions
function anadirEquipo () {
    var cantidad = +document.getElementById('cantidad').value || 1,
        selected = model.inventory.options[model.inventory.selectedIndex],
        choice;
    
    if (pageLoaded) {
        if (+selected.value !== 0) {
            model.quantity.value = +model.quantity.value + cantidad;

            while (cantidad-- > 0) {
                choice = document.createElement('option');
                choice.text = selected.text;
                choice.value = selected.value;

                model.equipos.add(choice);
            }
        }
    }
}

function retirarEquipos () {
    var options = model.equipos.options,
        i;
        
    if (pageLoaded) {
        for (i = 0; i < options.length; i) {
            if (options[i].selected) {
                model.equipos.remove(options[i]);
                model.quantity.value--;
            
            } else {
                i++;
            } 
        }
    }
}

// init
window.onload = function () {
    model = {
        inventory: document.getElementById('inventory'),
        equipos: document.getElementById('equipos'),
        quantity: document.getElementById('quantity')
    };
    
    pageLoaded = true;
};
```

```css
/* general */
*, .border-box {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* tr.output */
tr.output {
    vertical-align: top;
}

tr.output > td > * {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr class="input">
   <td align="center" bgcolor="#D4D4D4">
      <select id="inventory" size="1">
         <option id="0" value="0">Seleccione un equipo</option>
         <option id="bm260W" value="8060">Boviet Module(260W)</option>
         <option id="bm300W/305W/310W" value="156">Boviet Module(300/305/310W)</option>
      </select>
   </td>
   <td align="center" bgcolor="#D4D4D4">
      <input type="number" id="cantidad" placeholder="Ex: 5" size="1">
   </td>
</tr>
<tr class="actions">
   <td colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor="#D4D4D4">
      <!-- Añadir -->
      <button type="button" id="anadir" onclick="anadirEquipo()">Añadir</button>
      
      <!-- Retirar -->
      <button type="button" id="retirar" onclick="retirarEquipos()">Retirar</button>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <th align="center" bgcolor="#2AD2C9">
      <h4>Equipo(s) añadido(s):</h2>
   </th>
   <th align="center" bgcolor="#2AD2C9">
      <h4>Total:</h2>
   </th>
</tr>
<tr class="output">
   <td>
      <select id="equipos" multiple readonly>
      </select>
   </td>
   <td>
      <input type="number" id="quantity" value="0" readonly />
   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your availability and patience on helping me.

However, nothing happens upon clicking the "Anadir" button....

And I'm not sure I made myself 100% clear: this is an widget to request an order to a warehouse. So you choose the piece that you want and how many of it. Under "Equipos Anadidos" and "Total" should appear the selected item and how many of it, respectively. So, "quantity"="cantidad".

I will edit this post with the whole code. Hope that you can help me to understand why the button does not work :)

Comment: @eduroc92 Sorry for misunderstanding the question, lets do it!

Comment: @eduroc92 I'll do another answer, then I remove this one, since it's not what is supposed to be done!

Comment: Thank you so much :) 

This is how it looks like: http://imgur.com/a/84iob

When you click "Anadir", the selected option and its selected quantity of material should be replicated. Then, you should be able to add how many types of pieces you want. In the end, you would click "Enviar" to send your order request!

Comment: I am using 2stacks which allows me to program HTML, that first part of the code needs to be inside <script language="javascript"> ??