# populate second dropdown from first dropdown value and print value of input in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-2

this is my contoller

```
   public function add()
       {
           $data['gis'] = $this->Mymodel->get_gis_start();
           $data['side'] = 'tampil/side';
           $data['content']='ds/add_ds';
           $this->load->view('tampil/main',$data);

       }
```

this is my view

```
   <td><select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" name="pick_from" id="pick" onchange="populate(this.id,'drop')"><?php foreach($gis as $cit): ?>
<option value="<?php echo $cit->start_point; ?>"><?php echo $cit->start_point; ?></option><?php endforeach; ?>
</select></td>
<td><select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" name="pick_till" id="drop"></select></td>
<td><input name="total_loads" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" id="tl1" value="" onkeyup="sum(); sum();" placeholder="Total Loads Picked"></td>
```

this is my model

```
   function get_gis_start() 
       {
           $query = $this->db->get('gis');
           return $query->result();
       }
```

I want to populate second select with values selected from first dropdown and want to put the value of third input from database

my data base is 
This is the image of the database from which i want to fetch start_point and fill the select with id="pick" and end_point and fill the values related to start_point in select id="drop" and put the value of total_distance to the input value="values related to first select and second select" how can I do that kindly tell my I am very much struck

[image]

Comment: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFiWT.png)

Comment: Thank You Shashwat

Answer (score 0):

See the answer with the link given here Codeigniter dropdown

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45870578/how-to-create-a-dynamic-dropdown-based-on-values-of-another-dynamic-dropdown